# communication between two processes running node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a server, and decided to split up the work between different processes running node.js, because I heard node.js was single threaded and figured this would parallize better. The application is going to be a game. I have one process serving html pages, and then other processes dealing with the communication between clients playing the game. The clients will be placed into "rooms" and then use sockets to talk to each other relayed through the server. The problem I have is that the html server needs to be aware of how full the different rooms are to place people correctly. The socket servers need to update this information so that an accurate representation of the various rooms is maintained. So, as far as I see it, the html server and the room servers need to share some objects in memory. I am planning to run it on one (multicore) machine. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try this, maybe it works for you: [Fibers and Threads in node.js – what for?](http://bjouhier.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/fibers-and-threads-in-node-js-what-for/) I guess there were developments since you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Node currently doesn't support shared memory directly, and that's a reflection of JavaScript's complete lack of semantics or support for threading/shared memory handling.

With node 0.7, only recently usable even experimentally, the ability to run multiple event loops and JS contexts in a single process has become a reality (utilizing V8's concept of `isolates` and large changes to libuv to allow multiple event loops per process). In this case it's possible, but still not directly supported or easy, to have some kind of shared memory. In order to do that you'd need to use a Buffer or ArrayBuffer (both which represent a chunk of memory outside of JavaScript's heap but accessible from it in a limited manner) and then some way to share a pointer to the underlying V8 representation of the foreign object. I know it can be done from a minimal native node module but I'm not sure if it's possible from JS alone yet.

Regardless, the scenario you described is best fulfilled by simply using `child_process.fork` and sending the (seemingly minimal) amount of data through the communication channel provided (uses serialization).

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_processes.html

Edit: it'd be possible from JS alone assuming you used node-ffi to bridge the gap.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using a database like [Redis](http://redis.io) for this. You can have a process subscribed to a channel listening new connections and publishing from the web server every time you need.
You can also have multiple processes waiting for users and use a list and `BRPOP` to subscribe to wait for players.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to not do that.

Serving and message-passing are both IO-bound, which Node is very good at doing with a single thread. If you need long-running calculations about those messages, those might be good for doing separately, but even so, you might be surprised at how well you do with a single thread.

If not, look into Workers.

Answer (score 0):

zeromq is also becomming quite popular as a process comm method. Might be worth a look.  http://www.zeromq.org/ and https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node